# Click on a navbar button and go to the actual div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine a nav bar with different options (Home, Contact, Products, etc.), how can i do to click on Contact, and it goes to Contact on the website ? I mean, it goes down to find the right div.

Thanks a lot for your answers, if you need more infos, tell me !

Comment: `Anchor` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Take a look at [Anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Answer (score 0):

On your contact div add following link:

```
<p><a href="#contact">Contact</a></p>
```

and on div element you scrolling to give it same id:

```
<div id="contact"></div>
```

its called Anchor